# Artifactory, using curl to deploy an artifact not working (code 403)

Tags: artifactory

Novice Artifactory user here so please bear with.
Trying to use curl on linux to deploy a file in a repo and failing.  trying this running on the same server that's serving artifactory.

```
% --> curl -u my_idsid -X PUT 
"http://localhost:8081/artifactory/test_repo/test_artifact_linux_01" -T 
test_aftifact_linux_01
Enter host password for user 'my_idsid':<I entered the pw die my_user here>

HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: Artifactory/5.4.6
X-Artifactory-Id: 3444ab9991d26041:29864758:15e2f4940fa:-8000
Content-Type: application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 65
Date: Tue, 05 Sep 2017 21:00:20 GMT
Connection: close

{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 403,
    "message" : ""
  } ]
}
```

I was able to put (deploy) a file (an artifact) in this same repo from windows with the drag-drop method for that same user.  So I'm thinking that this confirms several things...
1) the repo exists
2) the permissions to allow that user write access is ok
3) the server is up and running ok
And the pw is OK, because when I intentionally enter something wrong, it comes up with a 401 instead.

I looked in artifactory.log and it has this for my attempt...

```
2017-09-05 17:15:00,332 [http-nio-8081-exec-7] [WARN ]
(o.a.w.s.RequestUtils:155) - Request /test_repo/test_artifact_linux_01 
should be a repo request and does not match any repo key
```

Does not match a repo key ?

I'm using the example here...

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-Example-DeployinganArtifact

and plugging in the repo name right after "artifactory" (replacing "my_repository") in the path.

I have a strong suspicion that I'm goofing up the path name, but I don't know what's wrong.  How does one determine the proper path to use ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

UPDATE:
My bad.  The repo was actually named "test-repo", not "test_repo".
Worked fine once I made that change.
Sorry for the false alarm.

Comment: Would it help if you fired up Developer Tools on the Windows box when you do the drag-and-drop that works? That way, you can see the HTTP requests that should hopefully include the headers and path you need.

Comment: could you also add the relevant part of the access.log file? the path indeed looks good. Another option would be for you to try with jfrog cli and see if it returns a more interesting error message.